# How do I swap two fields separated by backslash and output them separated by an at sign?

Tags: text-processing

Original file contains email addresses in the following format:

```
domain.com\first.lastname
```

I have used `sed` to replace the backslash with an `@` sign.

I've tried various suggestions to swap the `domain.com` and `first.lastname` fields.

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \@ \(.*\)/\2 - \1/' memberfile
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\s\(.*\)/\2 \1/' memberfile
sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) \- ([a-zA-Z0-9])*/\2 \- \1/' memberfile
```

All of the above just display `domain.com@first.lastname`...
I'm very green to sed!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\\\(.*\)/\2@\1/' memberfile
```

This assumes the file is still in the original slash-separated format. If it's in an @-separated format, try:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)@\(.*\)/\2@\1/' memberfile
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! That works perfectly! Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

Other ways without `sed`/regex:

```
awk -F\\ '{print $2"@"$1}' memberfile
```

or

```
cut -d\\ -f1 memberfile | paste -d@ memberfile - | cut -d\\ -f2
```